# Which package is responsible for switching input languages?

Tags: bug-reporting

I am trying to file a bug about language switching using a keyboard shortcut not working on my Unity desktop, but `ubuntu-bug` requires that I specify a package. Does anybody know which package is responsble for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep input
```

i think, its d-bus + xinput 
but short-key are handled by unity alone,

Comment: Already tried it. Reading the description of packages, I cannot see anything related. XInput's description tells that it manages configuration files.

Comment: lets wait for expert